# Why would attempting to execute a method "x" times per second give results that indicated it running greater/less times than x?

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, iteration, thread-sleep

I'm currently writing an Windows Form Application in which I connect to a server and send "x" "actions" a second to the server in order to stress test it. Once stopped, a .txt log is created detailing the number of actions sent and the time at which it was sent.

I attempt to verify the results by comparing the difference between a counter in the log after 1 second. However, upon doing this I found that there was inconsistency between what was in the log file and the intended number of actions to be sent.

For example, when attempting to send 50 actions/second there are no inconsistencies. Attempting 100 actions/second, only about 90 are being logged in the .txt, but attempting 1000 actions, 1300 are logged.

Initially I believed that the application was running into performance issues resulting in only 90 actions being logged when attempting to send 100. But I believe that's not the case due to when 1000 actions are attempted to be sent, 1300 are being logged. I further checked for performance issues using the Visual Studio Profiler and saw nothing of note.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this inconsistency?

CODE BELOW:

```
DateTime startTime;
TimeSpan executionTIme;

while (sendingActions)
{
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
    action = CreateNewAction();
    if (action != null)
    {
        actionCount++;
        SendAction(action);

        //Write to log
        tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt.fffffff") + " " + actionCount;
    }
    executionTime = DateTIme.Now.Subtract(startTime);


    //Sleeping thread to achieve "x" actions/second specified in ActionTime textbox
    Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(1 / (Convert.ToDouble(txtActionTime.Text)) * 1000 - executionTime.TotalMilliseconds));
}
```

Comment: Is always 90? How long is the program running for?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` does not guarantee exact time you specified. You can make `Thread.Sleep` more precisely via `timeBeginPeriod`, `timeEndPeriod` but it also does not guarantee exact time.

Comment: @SlaneR I'll give that a go and will report back in an edit.

Comment: @TimV `timeBeginPeriod` and `timeEndPeriod` also used something requires high precision sleeping, such as games. Try `timeBeginPeriod(1);`.

Comment: @SlaneR Tried that and still the same/similar results. Thought that might've done the trick for sure !

Comment: @tymtam Sorry I must've misremembered, I just tested it again and within the same run it is not consistently 90, it's around that area +/- 3

Comment: If you step through the code manually, does this also produce the same issues, or do the issues disappear?

Comment: @TheHeadmaster I'm not sure how I'd go about stepping through the code manually while preserving the functionality of the application. If I were to step through the code manually wouldn't the times at which the "actions" were sent have large gaps between them? The logs would just show me stepping through and sending the actions. I'll give it a go and let you know if I see anything odd though.

Comment: I may not have enough information to go on, but it's worth a shot to set break points on the log and the counter increment, and see if when the debugger is stepping through the code one happens more than the other. If it doesn't then it may be an issue with threading or binding (just a hunch) and if it is then it may be something else.

Comment: @TheHeadmaster Placing breakpoints on the log and counter and stepping through shows them both being reached. However, when I check the log file produced there is no output. If I just place a breakpoint on the counter, the log outputs fine. If I do the same on the logging, no output is produced. I don't know if that's related to the issue or is a separate issue to do with logging/breakpoints.

Comment: Hmm, that's really interesting. Unfortunately it sounds like the type of issue that I wouldn't be able to solve without looking at the code myself.